# Hive: how to show all partitions of a table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table with 1000+ partitions.

"`Show partitions`" command only lists a small number of partitions.

How can i show all partitions?

Update:

1. I found "`show partitions`" command only lists exactly 500 partitions.
2. "`select ... where ...`" only processes the 500 partitions!

Answer (score 96):

CLI has some limit when ouput is displayed. I suggest to export output into local file:

```
$hive -e 'show partitions table;' > partitions
```

Comment: Same result as CLI.  And it only shows 500 partitions. I don't known where is the magic number 500 from.

Comment: No idea then. It's very weird. Keep us posted if you solve it or find source of it. GL! Maybe naive but are you sure that there is more than 500 partitions?

Comment: Problem solved by "set cassandra.connection.sliceSize=10000;". Maybe it's a datastax's externsion to Hive.

Comment: is it feasible to show the created time of partition?

Comment: @colintobing its feasible when you query from the metastore_db

Comment: Why is this the most voted answer when, as the comments show, it still shows only 500 partitions?

Answer (score 26):

hive> show partitions table_name;

Comment: It showed numerous rows. Is it ok?

Comment: it depends on number of partitions .

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I'm writing this answer by extending wmky's answer above & also, assuming that you've configured mysql for your metastore instead of derby.

```
select PART_NAME FROM PARTITIONS WHERE TBL_ID=(SELECT TBL_ID FROM TBLS WHERE TBL_NAME='<table_name>');
```

The above query gives you all possible values of the partition columns.

***Example:***

```
hive> desc clicks_fact;
OK
time                    timestamp                                   
..                              
day                     date                                        
file_date               varchar(8)                                  

# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment             

day                     date                                        
file_date               varchar(8)                                  
Time taken: 1.075 seconds, Fetched: 28 row(s)
```

I'm going to fetch the values of partition columns.

```
mysql> select PART_NAME FROM PARTITIONS WHERE TBL_ID=(SELECT TBL_ID FROM TBLS WHERE TBL_NAME='clicks_fact');
+-----------------------------------+
| PART_NAME                         |
+-----------------------------------+
| day=2016-08-16/file_date=20160816 |
| day=2016-08-17/file_date=20160816 |
....
....
| day=2017-09-09/file_date=20170909 |
| day=2017-09-08/file_date=20170909 |
| day=2017-09-09/file_date=20170910 |
| day=2017-09-10/file_date=20170910 |
+-----------------------------------+

1216 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Returns all partition columns.

***Note: `JOIN` table `DBS` ON `DB_ID` when there is a DB involved (i.e, when, multiple DB's have same table_name)***

Answer (score 3):

You can see Hive MetaStore tables,Partitions information in table of "PARTITIONS".
You could use "TBLS" join "Partition" to query special table partitions.

Comment: Going into the hive mysql is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to communicate with Hive Metastore via Thrift protocol.
If you write code in python, you may benefit from [hmsclient](https://pypi.org/project/hmsclient/) library:

Hive cli:

```sql
hive> create table test_table_with_partitions(f1 string, f2 int) partitioned by (dt string);
OK
Time taken: 0.127 seconds

hive> alter table test_table_with_partitions add partition(dt=20210504) partition(dt=20210505);
OK
Time taken: 0.152 seconds
```

Python cli:

```py
>>> from hmsclient import hmsclient
>>> client = hmsclient.HMSClient(host='hive.metastore.location', port=9083)
>>> with client as c:
...    all_partitions = c.get_partitions(db_name='default',
...                                      tbl_name='test_table_with_partitions', 
...                                      max_parts=24 * 365 * 3)
...
>>> print([{'dt': part.values[0]} for part in all_partitions])
[{'dt': '20210504'}, {'dt': '20210505'}]
```

NB: `max_parts` is a parameter than cannot be greater than 32767 (java short max value).

If you have Airflow installed together with `apache.hive` extra, you create `hmsclient` quite easy:

```py
hive_hook = HiveMetastoreHook()
with hive_hook.metastore as hive_client:
    ... your code goes here ...
```

This seems a more valid way of communication with Hive Metastore than accessing DB directly (and database engine agnostic BTW).